# Eloquent save() throws internal server error

Tags: laravel, orm, eloquent, php-7, slim-3

I'm building some API app using Slim3 and Eloquent as ORM for model, and having some strange issue.

When I save model, I get internal server error, and can't catch error at all.
My model have only two columns, id pk autoincrement and name (string 255)
this is my settup:

Model:

```
class Version extends Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model
{
    protected $table = 'version';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['name'];

    protected $hidden = ['id'];
}
```

Action:

```
public function create(RequestInterface $request, ResponseInterface $response)
    {
        $params = $request->getParsedBody();
        $class = $this->model; //fully namespaced class name
        $model = new $class();
        $model->fill($params);

        return $model->save() ?
            $this->success($response, "{$this->getModelName()} successfully saved.") :
            $this->error($response, $model->errors());

    }
```

I manager to localize issue to this part of code in `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder`line #1242

```
if (in_array($method, $this->passthru)) {
            return call_user_func_array([$this->toBase(), $method], $parameters);
        }
```

But I have no idea what is wrong

EDIT:

I'm using `PHP/7.0.0-dev` and Slim `3.1`

Is Eloquent PHP 7 compatible?

Comment: When I updated PHP to ``7.0.3`` issue was fixed

Answer (score 0):

Your Model is a Eloquent Model so to create you can use following code

```
$version = App\Version::create(['name' => 'Your version name']);
```

This will remove all the unnecessary functions, and keept yuor code clean.

In your case make sure the  $request->getParsedBody(); 
returns the correct format for Eloquent to use it.

Comment: ``create()`` will eventually call ``save()`` so I get internal server error on using create too.